# Is it possible to delete an element from a pytorch tensor referentially?

Tags: memory, pytorch, tensor

Currently, I'm trying to delete an element in a vector corresponding to an index in pytorch, however, it keeps creating an extra copy with the methods I'm currently using.

This makes sense under the hood; the only way I'm thinking the memory address could remain the same is if the tensor was implemented like a linkedlist.

That being said, is it possible to delete an element from a PyTorch tensor referentially. i.e is it possible to delete an element from the tensor such that the tensor with the deleted index and the old tensor have the same memory address.

Methods I've already tried (but involved creating a copy/new memory address) involve (pseudocode)...

1. new_data = torch.cat((data[:i], data[i+1:))
2. data[torch.LongTensor(indices_to_keep)] where indices_to_keep = [index for index in range(data.shape[0]) if index != i]

Comment: What is your question precisely?

Comment: I re-edited the question. Mistakenly only put the question in the title. Thanks for the call out.

Comment: So you want to have a reference to a tensor such that when one of the elements in the first tensor is changed, the 2nd one - being a reference - changes too. Is that right?

Comment: yes!!! exactly! in python!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you don't need a special function to achieve such behavior. If you assign the existing tensor to a new variable, both variable names in that scope will be pointing to the same tensor.

```
x = torch.arange(5)
> tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

y = x # assign to y

# change y[0] which is x[0]
y[0] = -1 

x
> tensor([-1,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

Comment: Yes, this I know and it makes sense. My question is to do with deleting an index though from a tensor. For instance, in normal python you can do .pop(index) to a list and that referentially deletes the index from the list. Is there an analagous way for tensors?

In your clarrification above I thought you were alluding to what I meant my referentially updating, sorry if I caused any confusion.

Comment: There is no equivalent to `pop` in Pytorch since any removal or addition of elements would result in a copy of the whole tensor data. The underlying tensor data is contiguous in memory.